# Accept Email address with hyphen '-' sign in Opencart?

Tags: email, opencart, hyphenation

I am using opencart 2.0 for my website. Facing a problem email field don't accept email address having hyphen '-' sign in the address.

For instance email address:
abc@def-xyz.com

Now in this case it is showing invalid email id.

Comment: It's your won domain def-xyz . Gmail does not support "-" or "+".

Comment: No, I dont having email with dash but recently a customer want to register on my site having - in his email id and not able to register with this email id bcoz it shows invalid email id. Pls let me know which core files needed to edit and code to accept email with hyphen character.

Comment: If you upgrade to OpenCart 2.3.0.2, this works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `catalog/controller/account/register.php`, there is a regexp that controls the validation of the email.  (You'll see the call to `preg_match`.)  You want something like this (this will work):

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['email']) > 96) || !preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*.[a-z]{2,15}$/i', $this->request->post['email'])) {
  $this->error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
}
```

This logic was taken from OpenCart 2.0.1.1, which seems to have fixed the issue you are having.  And as I said in the comment above, it is fixed in 2.3.0.2, which is current as of June 2017.

Comment: You mean I have to edit file : catalog/controller/account/register.php and replace the above code you have provided. Please confirm.

Comment: Correct.  That is what you have to do.

Comment: But i am using Opencart 2.0.3 and the above code you have provided is identical in default file. Please confirm. Thanks

Comment: Then I guess I'm confused because this is the code that validates the email.  And if you run it against `abc@def-xyz.com`, it does not error. Are you sure that's the form of the email that's failing? Can you provide the actual email and just change a couple of characters?

Comment: You can check email for instance : contact@goo-gle.com like that. You can check in opencart 2.0.3.1. Kindly confirm

Comment: I don't have opencart 2.0.3.1.  But using the check in my answer, this email does not give an error.  So you'll have to look and find where else the email is being checked.  That was the only place I found in `controller/account/register.php` in version 2.0.1.1.